# How big should my subsample be?

Tags: mathematical-statistics

Say I have a dataset of 1 million high school students.

I'm trying to determine if test scores can be used to determine a successful college performance.

While the dataset has 1 million students, it has many more rows because I have multiple tests for each student.

What I'm trying to determine is if I should exclude some students because I don't have a sufficient quantity of tests and therefore including them could throw off my results.

For example, Student A, I have 20 tests to use as datapoints; but for Student B, I only have 2 tests. Should I keep Student B when conducting my analysis or drop Student B?

In other words, it makes me think there should be a way to calculate the required sample size of a subgroup in your larger sample.

Comment: Perhaps you could edit to explain why you want to exclude them. What bias to you think that would induce?

Comment: My 3rd paragraph goes into that. My thought is that by including a group of tests (aka a student) were I only have 2 data points might lead me to concluding the wrong results.

Comment: Why do you think it would cause you to conclude the wrong results?

Comment: The number of tests itself may be a good indicator of college performance, along with their results.  Dropping any of these data seems like a poor approach in principle, because it only loses potentially valuable information.  Why not instead adopt a suitable model and use a procedure appropriate for that model?

Comment: @whuber What would be a suitable model and procedure? Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: You haven't supplied enough information to permit any more than the most generic of comments.  With a million students there's potentially so much you could do that one would have to spend considerable time learning more about the data before it would be possible to give useful, defensible advice.

Answer (score 1):

The comments mentioned that you should first identify what kind of bias you're concerned about. My thought is that it is possible that correlation of test scores with college performance may vary based on the number of tests taken (there could be some confounding variable that affects both number of tests and college performance).

One thought i had on how you could incorporate all your scores is by using a bayesian model where you marginalize out the unknown test scores.